# inconsistent IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a query like:

```
@Query("select I from Indicator I where I.bankId in (:bankIds) ")
public List<Indicator> getIndicatorDetailsByBankIdList(@Param("bankIds") Set<Long> bankIdList);
```

This is working fine ***most of the time***. At times it's throwing the following exception.

```
Description - Parameter with that name [bankIds] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [bankIds] did not exist, StackTrace - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [bankIds] did not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.findParameterRegistration(BaseQueryImpl.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:631)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:49)
```

**Observations**

1. I'm not sure how right i'm adding in this observation, but i guess the service fails only when used inside modules which are little on the data heavy side (even here it fails only at times). Does memory issues cause these kind of exceptions to be thrown?
2. Inconsistant issue was observed on another method on the same entity:

```html
@Query("select I from Indicator I where I.activityId in (:activityIds) ")
     public List<Indicator> getIndicatorDetailsByActivityIdList(@Param("activityIds") Set<Long> acyIdList);
```

Comment: What error will you have if `bankIdList` is empty or `null`?

Comment: JPA allows to accept emtpy set or even null as argument, however, let's log the bankIdsList before calling the repository to catch the cause.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk Ok, just wondering what will be assigned to `(:bankIds)` so how does the query look like in whole then. Not so familiar with JPQL/HQL myself but using CriteriaQuery.

Comment: Please convert the bankIdList as string format. then it may execute properly. Try in this approach.

Comment: how is converting to string or removing the brackets a fix for this scenario? If those were the issues the service should fail every time right? And also i'm using JPA 2.1

Comment: What DB do you use?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g